# Alternatives to using property.setvalue() for efficiency purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

What alternatives are there to property.setvalue()? I've read that it is very slow. I'm using it to map IDataReader to POCO objects.

This is a truncated version of the code. Everything here is very new to me. I know there a lot of frameworks that accomplish this task. However, we can't use them.

```
public class DbAutoMapper<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> MapToList(IDataReader reader)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {                
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                foreach (var attribute in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                {                        
                    prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);                        
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this: "Using something somebody else wrote isn't an option."

Comment: Maybe he only accept an answer that is built on he's solution? idk.

Comment: Also - what is the point of the GetCustomAttributes call?  You're not doing anything with attribute...

Comment: Why don't you use a `DataTable` instead? That would be much more efficient. `var dt = new DataTable();dt.Load(reader);` finished.

Comment: I took some of the code out. That is for an attribute that has the db column name to map to.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Then map the DT to my POCO? Isn't that the same kind of issue? Or, can you easily map DT to POCO?

Comment: Sorry, i overlooked the POCO part of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly: why are you repeating the reflection for every attribute,  when you don't *use* the attribute?

Second: assuming you intended to map this by name, column-to-property (which isn't what the code currently does), consider a tool like [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper), which **does all this for you**, including cached high-performance reflection-emit. It'll also handle the command itself for you. For example:

```
string region = "North";
var customers = conn.Query<Customer>(
    @"select * from Customers where Region = @region",
    new { region } // full parameterization, the easy way
).ToList();
```

If you need more control, consider [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember), which provides fast member-access (again, reflection-emit), but without being specific to data access:

```
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(T)); 
string propName = // something known only at runtime 
while( /* some loop of data */ ) {
    var obj = new T();
    foreach(var col in cols) {
        string propName = // ...
        object cellValue = // ...
        accessor[obj, propName] = cellValue;
    }
    yield return obj;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the emit / code weaving approach.  It's like code generation - without the code!

Comment: @RQDQ but the good thing is - both "dapper" and "FastMember" keep the gory details of IL generation away from harming the sanity of the developer :)

Comment: @Gert some damned crazy fool with a "thing" for il-emit

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there any possibility to speed up the same property access way in PCL?

Comment: @AlexanderLogger not AFAIK

Comment: @MarcGravell just discovered https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey and CacheableInvocation really increased 'get' performance twice after replacing slow reflection way. https://github.com/Taggersoft/SharpTL/commit/9cf4ac5f45a380029a8238692051ff8b0cfa9c5c

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches come to mind...

**Skip Reflection**

```
public class DbAutoMapper<T> where T : IInitFromReader, new()
{
    public IEnumerable<T> MapToList(IDataReader reader)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {                
            IInitFromReader obj = new T;

            obj.InitFromReader(reader);

            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then you'll have to implement the InitFromReader in each of your entitiy objects.  Obviously, this skips the benefits of reflection (less code).

**Code Generation**

Maintaining this code for (InitFromReader) is painful, so you could opt to generate it.  This in many ways gives you the best of both worlds:

- You don't have to maintain (by hand) a lot of code
- You don't take the performance hit of reflection.